# Proving a factor of a Mersenne number

Tags: number-theory

[image]

'Given the result that (2/47)=1, prove that 47 is a factor of M_23'
Can someone provide me a hint on how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Euler Criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Bigl(\dfrac 2{47}\Bigr)=1 $, we can write $\,2\equiv a^2 \mod 47 $ for some $a$,  and use Little Fermat:

$$M_{23}=2^{23}-1=a^{46}-1\equiv 1-1=0\mod 47.$$

Comment: For Fermat's Little Theorem its: a^p-1 ≡ 1 (modp). Sorry I'm new to this forum and studying math. Do I make 2^47-1 ≡1 (mod 47)?

Comment: ??? What do you mean?

Comment: Don't worry - thanks anyway.

Comment: I gave the details in my updated answer. Hope it's clear now.